# Which columns are binary in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a large number of columns and I need to find which columns are binary (with values 0 or 1 only) without looking at the data. Which function should be used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no direct function to test for this.  Rather, you need to build something based on how the data was encoded (e.g. 1/0, T/F, True/False, etc.).  In addition, if your column has a missing value, the entire column will be encoded as a float instead of an int.

In the example below, I test whether all unique non null values are either '1' or '0'.  It returns a list of all such columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bool': [1, 0, 1, None], 
                   'floats': [1.2, 3.1, 4.4, 5.5], 
                   'ints': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'str': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

bool_cols = [col for col in df 
             if df[[col]].dropna().unique().isin([0, 1]).all().values]

# 2019-09-10 EDIT (per Hardik Gupta)
bool_cols = [col for col in df 
             if np.isin(df[col].dropna().unique(), [0, 1]).all()]

>>> bool_cols
['bool']

>>> df[bool_cols]
   bool
0     1
1     0
2     1
3   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. Worked!

Comment: Works, except the `.unique()` doesn't seem to be valid as of `0.18.1`. 

One somewhat hidden trick is that this works for columns that are explicitly boolean, i.e `False`, `True`, rather than just `0` and `1`. This is because python apparently automatically casts; `False in [0,1]` returns `True`

Comment: `[col for col in df if np.isin(df[col].unique(), [0, 1]).all() ]`, this should be updated answer

Answer (score 6):

```
def is_binary(series, allow_na=False):
    if allow_na:
        series.dropna(inplace=True)
    return sorted(series.unique()) == [0, 1]
```

This is the most efficient solution I found. It is quicker than the answers above. When handling large data sets, the difference in timing becomes relevant.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the answer just above, using value_counts().index instead of unique() should do the trick:

```
bool_cols = [col for col in df if 
               df[col].dropna().value_counts().index.isin([0,1]).all()]
```

Comment: This will pass for columns with no values because `all` returns `True` on empty lists. I don't think that would desirable.

Answer (score 3):

Using Alexander's answer, with python version - 3.6.6

```
[col for col in df if np.isin(df[col].unique(), [0, 1]).all()]
```

Comment: You first need to `.dropna()` before calling `.unique()`, but thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Improving upon @Aiden to avoid returning an empty column:

```
[col for col in df if (len(df[col].value_counts()) > 0) & all(df[col].value_counts().index.isin([0, 1]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late. But seeing that one may also need to get columns with binary-occuring features not necessarily already in [0,1] format, i.e. "Yes/No" , "True/False",  the following could do.

```
binary_cols= [col for col in df.columns if len(df[col].unique())==2]
binary_cols
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the unique() function from pandas on each column in your dataset.

ex: `df["colname"].unique()`

This will return a list of all unique values in the specified column.

You can also use for loop to traverse through all the columns in the dataset.

ex: `[df[cols].unique() for cols in df]`

Answer (score 0):

Many years late, but here is my answer using `nunique()`:

```
[col for col,val in df.nunique().items() if val==2]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?